# MySQL Left Join Duplication

Tags: mysql, duplicates, left-join

TABLE A: qa_invoices

```
    invoice_code   invoice_date
    1              25
    2              25
    3              26
    4              27
```

TABLE B: qa_invoicesitems

```
   invoice_code   item_quantity    item_name
   1              2                Mouse
   1              1                CPU
   2              5                Keyboard
   3              1                Router
   4              3                Switch
```

My Query:

```
SELECT SUM(qa_invoicesitems.item_quantity) AS item_count, COUNT(*) AS invoice_count    
FROM qa_invoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN qa_invoicesitems USING (invoice_code) 
WHERE qa_invoices.invoice_date = 25
```

My Result:

```
item_count  invoice_count
8           3
```

I have hours and hours looking for a solution to this, the problem is to count the Invoices (invoice_count).

The correct result would be:

```
item_count  invoice_count
8           2
```

if someone can help me with my poblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DISTINCT to your COUNT.

```
SELECT SUM(qa_invoicesitems.item_quantity) AS item_count, COUNT(DISTINCT(qa_invoicesitems.invoice_code)) AS invoice_count    
FROM qa_invoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN qa_invoicesitems USING (invoice_code) 
WHERE qa_invoices.invoice_date = 25
```